# How to create files inside a folder in python

Tags: python, file, imagemagick, directory

I am trying to convert a pdf to image using Imagemagick and python and below are my codes

The following file takes pdf file as input from command line and converts to image

**convert.py**

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError
from os.path import isfile

filename = sys.argv[1]

try:
    if isfile(filename):
        check_call(["convert", "-density", "150", "-trim",
                    filename, "-quality", "100", "-scene", "1", 'hello.jpg'])
except (OSError, CalledProcessError, TypeError) as e:
    print "-----{0}-----".format(e)
```

Above code is working fine and after running the file,my directory structure with resultant file is

```
codes
     convert.py
     example.pdf
     hello.jpg
```

But what all i want is to create the resultant image(jpg) file inside a folder with name of the pdf file like below

```
codes
     convert.py
     example.pdf
     example/
            hello.jpg
```

So can anyone please let me know how to create a directory dynamically with pdf name `if not exists` as above and create a jpg file like above

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.splitext` to strip the file extension. Something like this:

```
if isfile(filename):
    dirname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
        os.mkdir(dirname)
    outfile = os.path.join(dirname, "hello.jpg")
    check_call(["convert", "-density", "150", "-trim",
                filename, "-quality", "100", "-scene", "1", outfile])
```

**EDIT:**

To have the new directory in the current working directory and not in the parent directory of the input file, use `os.path.basename()` and `os.getcwd()`:

```
dir_base = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dir_base)
```

Comment: k if i do as above, when i given the input file as "python convert.py /home/user/pdfs/example.pdf" , then the code is generating "example/hello.jpg" in the directory "/home/user/pdfs/", but what all i want is to create the folder where code file i.e., convert.py exists